# Shorter delay in android slideshow

Tags: android

So im making a slideshow in android that i want to move very fast to look almost as though an animation. Bellow is the code that i am using but i want it go move faster(smaller delay) but i cant make the postDelay any smaller. How would i do this? If its not possible what would a better way to do this be?

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             myslideshow();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
                }

        };

     private void myslideshow()
            {
                 if (position < imageIDs.length){
                     iv.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
                     position++;
                 }
                 else{
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);                       
                 }                          
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the [Android Animation API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) help instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gallery. On click of some button or anything you can run a for loop to 
display next element in the gallery till the last element (image in your case) is displayed

Comment: can you give an example of doing this

Comment: For gallery you could refer:    http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html